# Updatable d3 Chord Diagram

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, chord-diagram

I'd like to modify [d3's Chord Diagram](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006):

[image]

I would like to allow values to be updated. This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YRWsv/1/) contains my code so far, but I'm stuck as the ticks and their labels don't seem to update (click on the link to update with new matrix). The rest of it seems to work fine (I think...).

I think the problem is that the ticks are within a tick group. I can't get my head around how to remove them or the entire tick group (see for the '???' in the code).

```
ticks.remove();
```

and/or

```
tickGroups.remove();
```

don't result in the expected outcome.

Comment: This seems to be a tough one, or all the d3 guns are enjoying the summer ;-). Let me know if I can do anything to make the question more comprehendible.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://exposedata.com/tutorial/chord/latest.html)?

Comment: It does not look at first blush like your tick values are changing with the click? I guess I am not sure what it is supposed to do? Maybe you can update the example to actually pass in a set of hard coded tick values? In the meantime this is worth a detailed read-through and might help: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/

Comment: @Lars: No I didn't know this before. Thanks for this link. I guess I go with an easier version of deleting the scale rather than moving it.

Comment: @Superboggly: The data is changed (and static) as you can see by the chords moving, so I would expect the same for the scale...